# Migrate SharePoint 2010 rbs to SharePoint 2013 sql

Tags: migration, rbs

We have a SharePoint 2010 Farm using rbs and would like to migrate it to a SharePoint 2013 Farm using sql. Can this be done by using the detach method on the WSS_Content database or is there another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old, but I wanted to post my solution.

We were able to migrate the databases with the RBS still attached. I was able to go [Microsoft RBS Library](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271938) to download the library on each 2013 WFE server. **NOTE**:  Do not run the configuration wizard it installs features that are not compatible with SharePoint 2013. Instead Save the file to the location C:\RBSClient (I created the location)

Run the Command Prompt as an Administrator and paste the following code

`cd c:\RBSClient`

**First**

```
msiexec /qn /lvx* rbs_install_log.txt /i RBS_amd64.msi TRUSTSERVERCERTIFICATE=true FILEGROUP=PRIMARY DBNAME="<database>" DBINSTANCE="<DBSERVER>" FILESTREAMFILEGROUP=RBSFilestreamProvider FILESTREAMSTORENAME=<FileStreamName>
```

**Second**

```
msiexec /qn /lvx* rbs_install_log.txt /i RBS_amd64.msi DBNAME="<database>" DBINSTANCE="<DBServer>" ADDLOCAL=Client,Docs,Maintainer,ServerScript,FilestreamClient,FilestreamServer

msiexec /qn /lvx* rbs_install_log.txt /i RBS_amd64.msi DBNAME="<Database>" DBINSTANCE="<DBserver>" ADDLOCAL=Client,Docs,Maintainer,ServerScript,FilestreamClient,FilestreamServer
```

**NOTE:**  The first code is the initial install of the RBS Client and should only be ran once. The second code is for each other content database. This is done on each server.

After the library is installed on each Web Server Enable RBS for each content database on just one server by running the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell application as an administrator and pasting the following code.

```
$cdb = Get-SPContentDatabase <database>
$rbss = $cdb.RemoteBlobStorageSettings
$rbss.Installed()
$rbss.Enable()
$rbss.SetActiveProviderName($rbss.GetProviderNames()[0])
$rbss
```

Make sure the app pool account has **dbOwner**, at this point documents should be able to open using the filestream provider. To migrate them to SQL database use the following code.

```
$rbs=(Get-SPContentDatabase <database>).RemoteBlobStorageSettings
$rbs.GetProviderNames()
$rbs.SetActiveProviderName("")
$rbs.Migrate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot migrate directly a DB with RBS enabled, You have to move all the files inside the DB then you can use backup & restore method.

The steps you need to follow are:

- Stop Content Db to use RBS and Move in all the Files inside the DB
  from Blob Folder.
- Verity that files are inside Sql DB by running query.
- Test by uploading file to Site and verify it stores in sql DB.
- backup and restore the DB to your new SharePoint 2013 environment.
- Test it.
- Configure the RBS on SharePoint 2013 Farm after upgrade. link to the
  planning for RBS :
  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748638.aspx

http://sharepoint-community.net/forum/topics/sharepoint-2010-to-2013-upgrade-migration-with-rbs

http://www.quercussolutions.com/blog/index.php/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2013-upgrade-issue-content-database-cannot-be-upgraded-due-to-use-of-the-obsoleted-external-binary-storage-feature/